# XSLT select all text

Tags: xslt

I want to select all text and do a search and replace.
I want to turn all dashed into non-breaking dashes.

I am using [this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426073/xslt1-0-replace-is-not-working) for the search and replace part,
now I just need to run all text thru it..

Comment: You need some test data to show what you are trying to match.

Comment: Sure.. https://gist.github.com/1184890

Comment: And when you say text? Surely you don't mean the entire document? Do you just mean the text nodes (retaining the structure)?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution, using the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: I do mean all of the text, headlines, paragraphs, etc. any node content, not node attributes

Comment: Dimitre, do you recommend I don't use the template I referenced above for other search and replace functions?

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: I haven't looked at your current code. You cn use my solution as a second step -- apply it on the output of your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't know what do you mean by "non-breaking dash", but here is a simple solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="vRep" select="'&#8212;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-', $vRep)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document, the result is the same document in which any `'-'` is replaced by whatever is specified as the value of the global parameter $vRep**.

**For example, when applied on this XML document**:

```
<a>
 <b>Hi - hi</b>
 - - -
 <c>
   <d>Wow... - cool</d>
 </c>
 - - -
</a>
```

**the result is**:

```
<a>
  <b>Hi — hi</b>
 — — —
 <c><d>Wow... — cool</d></c>
 — — —
</a>
```

**Explanation**:  Use of the identity rule, overriden by a template matching any text node, and translating any `'-'` character in it to the character contained in `$vRep` -- by using the standard XPath function `translate()`.

Comment: +1 for use of simple [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function.

Comment: This looks great, but I can't seem to get it to work.. it isn't throwing an error, just isn't processing anything for some reason..

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: This transformation, when applied on ***any*** XML document, replaces the `'-'` with whatever is specified in `$vRep`. You may be trying to combine it with your code and this is your problem. Learn how to perform multi-pass transformations.